# How do I append to a list within a cell of a data frame in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append

I'm hoping to get some feedback on this issue I'm experiencing. I've been working on this for a bit and can't seem to find my way through to a solution. Here's my code:

```
temporary_interval_list = list(time_based_tempo_analysis.loc[working_list_date_index, 'intervals'])
temporary_interval_list.append(int(working_separation_list[j-1]))
time_based_tempo_analysis.at[working_list_date_index, 'intervals'] = temporary_interval_list
```

I have a list within a cell of a data frame. I am pulling that list and appending a new int to it then attempting to replace the list back into the same cell within the same data frame. I am getting this error:

> ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

To give a running example of how this works, for instance: at index `723` in the `interval` column of the data frame, there is a list `[2]`. Then I pull a value from a separate list, in this case, `working_separation_list` of say `[34]` and I want to append that to the `temporary_interval_list` so it becomes `[2, 34]` and then replace the value at index `723` in column `interval` with the newly updated list `[2,34]`.

Any pointers to what I might be missing would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I'm unable to reproduce your error with just the info given – would you be able to post a reproducible example? I tried: `df = pd.DataFrame({"intervals": [[3], [45], [2]]}, index=[721, 722, 723])` and then `df.at[723, "intervals"] = [2, 34]` and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and feedback! So using your example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"intervals": [[3], [45], [2]]})`
`df.at[1, "intervals"] = [2, 34]`

I changed the index to `1` because we want to use a working code.

The result I am looking for should be 
`intervals
0 [3]
1 [2, 34, 45]
2 [2]`

but what I am getting from your code is :

`intervals
0 [3]
1 [2, 34]
2 [2]`